# Acer V3-571 came pre-installed with Windows 8: possible to install Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I recently got an Acer V3-571 which came pre-installed with Windows 8. I want to install Ubuntu on it. So far the solutions say to disable secure boot. However, when I go to the boot options, I am unable to change it.

1. When the boot option is "UEFI", Secure Boot is enabled, and I cannot go down to change it.
2. When I change the boot option to "Legacy BIOS", when the computer restarts, it is unable to even detect Windows 8.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on this computer?

Answer (score 0):

First, Microsoft's certification program requires that users *must* be able to disable Secure Boot on x86/x86-64 computers that bear a Windows 8 logo. Thus, there almost certainly is a way to do it. Unfortunately, there's no standardization in user interfaces on this matter, so you might need to dig deeper or call tech support to find out how to do it. If you have to call tech support, be sure to complain, and follow up with a letter.

Second, Ubuntu 12.10 ships with Secure Boot support, so it's theoretically possible to install it on a computer that uses Secure Boot even without disabling that feature. I say "theoretically" because this support is *very* new, and some people seem to have problems with it. Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't provide Secure Boot support, so getting it to install with Secure Boot active is much harder. (It's not impossible, but it's so hard that it's not practical for anything but experts.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable UEFI in your BIOS
2. Follow the 1st paragraph of the UEFI Community Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI